# Where can I get a list of all errors & warnings?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, warnings

Is there some place where I can get a **list** of all Visual C++ **compiler/linker errors/warnings**? I am looking for both the error/warning number and the error/warning text that is displayed by the compiler. MSDN has them all, but they are linked to on individual pages.

Comment: Good question. I'd like to know, too. MSDN doesn't bother presenting them in any sort of convenient format.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, none exists: googling for a single page containing all the terms `lnk1000 lnk1003 c4100` yields no results.

I think you'll have to compile a reference yourself by painstaking navigation through [this MSDN section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x5x43k7.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Al list of all warnings for VS2015 and VS2017 can be found at sections such as
[C++ Core Guidelines Checker Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-for-cpp-corecheck),
[Code Analysis for C/C++ Warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-for-c-cpp-warnings),
and other related sections linked from the References header in the left menu.

For example, here is a document describing [C6001: using uninitialized memory [variable]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6001).

I am not sure if there is a single page covering all warning codes, but lacking one, you can clone the documentation sources and search through it yourself: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/tree/master/docs/code-quality